# RichTextBox issues for Chinese characters( WPF)

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

Hy,

I have a Richtextbox control and I want to display Chinese characters; but instead my control displays "?" question marks instead of mystring.
 mystring = DO的目的就是为了保持字母多多少少标准及平均 and this is what I receive in my Richtextbox: DO???????????????????????

This is the property used to read mystring.

```
public string Test
    {
        get
        {
            return this.test != null ? RtfToText.ConvertRtfToText(this.test) : null;
        }
    }

    <RichTextBox>
      <FlowDocument>
              <Paragraph>
               <Run Text="{Binding Path=Test, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
              </Paragraph>
     </FlowDocument>
     <xctk:RichTextBoxFormatBarManager.FormatBar>
     <xctk:RichTextBoxFormatBar />
     </xctk:RichTextBoxFormatBarManager.FormatBar>                                               
   </RichTextBox>
```

Comment: change font to the one which supports those symbols